# web service error

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services

i am trying to make web service but i am getting this error

```
IWAB0506E Error when copying Axis jar files to web project
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /lib/saaj.jar
    at
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like a bug in eclipse WTP - [you're not alone](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=83788).

Following this other thread, you be lucky with [deleting (moving/renaming)](http://forum.springsource.org/showpost.php?p=280729&postcount=6) one library:

```
javax.xml.soap_1.3.0.v200904281458.jar
```

Or try to upgrade your environment to the latest and greatest.

Comment: where is the library located?

Comment: @chinna_82 - it depends. If you use eclipse it is in \eclipse\plugins\ folder.

Comment: This problem happened to me with a fresh eclipse j2ee Version: 2023-09 (4.29.0). The links in this answer are not valid since spring moved forums.

Comment: I was able to solve my problem with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150698/eclipse-axis-error-when-creating-web-service

Answer (score 1):

This second patch does the same thing, but instead of using a java system property, it uses a hidden eclipse preference as the flag to disable the copy.

This preference can be enabled by editing the below file

```
<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.jst.ws.axis.consumption.ui.prefs
```

add the line `disableAxisJarCopy=true`

Answer (score 0):

Browse tho the eclipse workspace:

```
<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.jst.ws.axis.consumption.ui.prefs
```

Sometime, if you do not have this file created, then create this file
Add the following entry and save the file:

```
eclipse.preferences.version=1
disableAxisJarCopy=true
```