# Eclipse Axis error when creating web service

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, axis

Every time I try to create a new Web Service in Eclipse, I get this error:

```
IWAB0489E Error when deploying Web service to Axis runtime
  axis-admin failed with  {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}HTTP (404)Not Found
```

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Are that all errors in your server console? Is axis registered in your web.xml?

Comment: No, I get the error from Eclipse. Axis seems to be registered in web.xml (or there are at least some servlet-mappings; I'm new to this so I don't know what the correct configuration is. Thanks

Comment: I think that Renato's answer should be the accepted answer, not Sumit Singh's answer.

Comment: According to a comment on Sumit's answer, it seems the poster got their problem solved with his help, so that should be the accepted answer, right?

Answer (score 30):

In fact this problem occur because you have choosen Axis1 instead Axis2 when trying to generate the WebService.

To change from Axis1 to Axis2 you need to click in "Web service runtime: Apache Axis" when on this step of the creation of the web service:

[image: Web service creating]

Then, change from Axis to Axis 2:

[image: Choose Axis 2]

One last consideration:
You must be sure that in the creation moment of your Web Dynamic Project, you have choosen "Dynamic Web Module Version" to be below 3.0. Version 2.5 will work. After that you need to add "Axis2 Web Services" to the facets of the project. Right click on the project > Properties > Project Facets

[image: Adding Axis2 to the project facets]
check the  box publish the web service and in client select the sliding bar create client .
if the problem occurs any then restart your eclipse.
Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

I needed axis1 for my project (since axis2 created some new problems) & had this problem. I solved it by the following steps:

- Go to **Project Explorer** in Eclipse.
- Delete **Servers** project.
- Go to **Window** > **Preferences** > **Server** > **Runtime Environments**.
- Remove current server & create again.

Answer (score 0):

You must enable the "web.xml" Web Deployment Descriptor file when creating project and you still use axis 1.
I did it and everything worked fine.